# react-styleguidist use of TS in examples in MD files

Tags: typescript, tsx, react-styleguidist, styleguidist

I would like to use TypeScript in Markdown files with React-Styleguidist, but I consistently encounter a SyntaxError. I would appreciate help in resolving this specific issue.

Here are the steps I have taken:

- I set up a React project with React-Styleguidist to generate documentation based on my components.
- I created Markdown files (.md) to document my React components.
- I added TypeScript code within these Markdown files to describe the component's property types.
- When I attempt to generate the documentation with **React-Styleguidist**, I receive a `**SyntaxError**` indicating a syntax issue in my **TypeScript** code.
- I have conducted online research to find solutions, but I have not found a clear answer to this particular problem.

Here are some additional details that may be helpful:

- I am using the "^13.1.1" version of **React-Styleguidist**.
- I have confirmed that TypeScript is properly installed and up to date on my machine.

This is my **styleguide.config.js** :

```
module.exports = {
  components: './src/components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
  webpackConfig: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'esbuild-loader',
              options: {
                loader: 'tsx',
                target: 'es2017',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
  },
};
```

Button.md :

```
    interface ButtonProps {
      title: string;
    }
    
    const handleButtonClick = ({ title }: ButtonProps): void => {
      console.log(title);
    };
    
    <Button onClick={() => handleButtonClick({ title: 'test' })}>Push Me</Button>

Button.tsx :

import React, { ReactNode, MouseEventHandler } from "react";

interface ButtonProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  styles?: React.CSSProperties;
  className?: string;
  handleChange?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({
  children,
  styles,
  className,
  handleChange,
}) => {
  return (
    <button style={styles} className={className} onClick={handleChange}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

My build result :

[image]

Doc error :

[image]

Comment: What is your `tsconfig.json` ?

Comment: @dhaker I don't have a tsconfig.json file. What is the use of the library used?

Comment: Try to add a `tsconfig.json` with only `ts` and `tsx` files in `include` section of it, it may help.

Comment: @dhaker this is my ```tsconfig.json``` ,  the error is same : {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

Comment: I missed that error is coming from `Button.tsx` file and not from `Button.md` file, please add the content of `Button.tsx` file

Comment: @dhaker I edited the post you will find the code of Button.tsx.

Comment: @dhaker If the error came from the tsx file I would have an error when compiling. But no problem when launching ```npx styleguidist server```

Comment: I have a new track I have the impression that it does not take into account my loader  : ``` You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders ```